# MemoryMappedFile wait handle and Mutex

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get the `WaitHandle` from a `MemoryMappedFile`? The assigned name seems to conflict with trying to fetch or create a Mutex using the same name.

```
const string name = "tobyd";
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(name, 64);
Mutex mx = new Mutex(true, name); // bang! sadness.
```

If I use the `Mutex.TryOpenExisting` static I get back `false` and null in the out param. To no surprise.

What in MemoryMappedFile is using up this reference name? How would you wait on a MMF to be release to be able to re-use the name?

Comment: Why not just generate a randomized string as name? The name is a arbitrary identifier. As long as you (or the Dispose Code) takes care of releasing that handle properly, any string should do.

Comment: Or if you look at this it shows how you can work with the mutex  to add delays so you could queue up behind waiting for access.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm more interested in why the MMF identifier interferes with the Mutex identifier (they are different concepts in my head, perhaps not to the OS though?) and how you'd go about waiting on reusing the name that *may* be assigned to one of at least two different abstractions.

Comment: Maybe use vars...

Comment: You can get the MMF handle using it's `SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle` property value. As for the name, yes, these kind of object share a common Windows namespace. To see this, run WinObj as administrator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj and navigate to `\Sessions\[N]\BaseNamedObjects` (replace [N] by the proper value, on my PC it's 3), you'll see tobyd as a `Section` for the MMF and as a `Mutant` for the Mutex. Different types but same names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified a memory mapped file is a operative system construct for mapping a file into virtual memory, without reading the whole file from disk.

Instead it's accessing the actual medium (HDD, SSD, NAS, ...) as it was in memory.
This is a cross process construct, to ensure no more than one instance (process/thread) writes to it simultaneously some kind of lock is needed.

Without knowing I would assume that Windows is using a Mutex with the mapName (filename) to solve this.

[Further reading (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)

**Edit**

When decompiling the class [MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) you will notice that it's using the windows kernel32 function [CreateFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) which states that:

> If lpName matches the name of an existing event, semaphore, mutex, waitable timer, or job object, the function fails, and the GetLastError function returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. This occurs because these objects share the same namespace.

The argument mapName in the static method `MemoryMappedFile.CreatOrOpen` will be passed on to lpName in the call to `CreateFileMapping`

If that statement is true, this code will also fail:

```
const string name = "tobyd";
Mutex mx = new Mutex(true, name);
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(name, 64); // bang! sadness.
```

In light of that I think my original assumption was right.